# Drop all sequences SqlAlchemy

Tags: database, sqlalchemy, sequence

I'm using SqlAlchemy with PostgreSql. I'm creating lots of sequences. I'm trying to drop all the tables and sequences. But couldn't drop sequences. How can I drop all the sequences in SqlAlchemy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the  solution.

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/test', echo=True)
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
```

It drops all the tables including sequences.

Comment: doesnt work for me, all sequences are stay presented after `drop_all()`